# Authenticate in Sheets Add-on to App Using Google OAuth

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth, google-sheets-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I am creating a Sheets add-on that works with our app. Our app uses Google OAuth for authentication.

I have the add-on working with manually configured credentials, but obviously that's not a real life solution. Now I need to have the add-on user authenticate to our app within the add-on itself, so we know whose account to work with.

User has data in Sheets -> user uses add-on to authenticate to app -> add-on uses app's API to push/pull data between Sheets and app for that user

I have tried using our API's login URL to get the HTTPResponse from Google using fetch() and loading it into a sidebar, but aside from it being ugly, it doesn't give me the expected option of choosing the Google account I want, but rather logging in from scratch, and when I enter my Google account, it doesn't do anything other than continue giving me errors about the frame being sandboxed. The threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400233/issue-with-embedding-google-apps-script-in-an-iframe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014127/window-postmessage-to-script-google-com-as-popup) don't seem to address the issues as they're talking about iframe within the app, whereas I'm trying to use the [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) in Sheets itself.

The app and the add-on are using the same GCP Project ID.

I need to get the same BearerToken that the app uses to use in the add-on.

Comment: So, you're trying to make an HTTP Request from the sidebar (client side) to your API?  Does the user need to authorize an external request (UrlFetchApp.fetch() ) to use your add-on?

Comment: hey were you able to figure this out? I need to do something similar.